# Apache not listening on port 443

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, ssl

I've purchased an SSL and I'm trying to set it on a browser.
The port is forwarded in the router to the server, and I believe that SSL certificate is installed correctly (the apache starts OK).

I opened the port in the IPtables firewall, but when I list the port listened - I don't see anything listening to port 443.

I went over my configuration (default debian 7 w/ with LAMP server) and I have the following in my ports.conf file:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
     NameVirtualHost *:443
     Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

And in the sites-enabled I have a file called default-ssl containing (it's quite long, i'll just add the host data, not the entire ssl file options unless someone can think it could help)

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
#               Order allow,deny
#               allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on


    #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
    #   the ssl-cert package. See
    #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.
    #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
    #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/dev.webmark.co.il/dev_webmark_co_il.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/dev.webmark.co.il/dev.webmark.co.il.key

    #   Server Certificate Chain:
    #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
    #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
    #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
    #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
    #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
    #   certificate for convinience.
    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

    #   Certificate Authority (CA):
    #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
    #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
    #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
    #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
    #         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
```

So I apologize for the very long post, just thought this is relevant information.

I think the ports.conf file enables the listener on 443, but I don't know why it doesn't.

When I list the ports listening:

```
netstat -a | egrep 'Proto|LISTEN'
```

I get

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.10:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:35563                 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:sunrpc                *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:61619         *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:61620                 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ftp                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.10:8888          *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp          *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:27017                 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:sunrpc             [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 localhost:smtp          [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:https              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:55644              [::]:*                  LISTEN
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7400     /tmp/mongodb-27017.so                                                                                        ck
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7444     /var/run/dbus/system_                                                                                        bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7215     /var/run/rpcbind.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     3434     /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7351     /var/run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7624     /var/run/mysqld/mysql
```

I'm pretty sure that the condition  is true. I hope I gave all the relevant information and not too much of it.
Thanks for your time reading this.
Yan

**Edit**
in order to make sure mod_ssl is running - I used

```
apache2ctl -M
```

Which resulted with:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

**/edit**

Comment: Well... to me, Apache is carefully listening on `[::]:https`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Port 443 is HTTPS. From your `netstat` output:

```
tcp6       0      0 [::]:https              [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

It is clear that a process is listening on port 443. To confirm whether the above is Apache (httpd) process, it is important to run the command as root. Use `ss` instead as `netstat` is deprecated:

```
# ss -tlnp
```

Comment: Seems you are right - I'll have to go over the entire flow to see if the port is indeed forwarded to the server and opened in IP tables. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Did you enable `mod_ssl`? Since you're running Debian, this is the way to do it (run as root, or via sudo):

```
a2enmod ssl
```

Comment: Thanks Steven Monday, when I use "apache2ctl -M" I see it in the list. I'll edit the original question and add the full input I get.